# Bootstrap path in .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I setup Bootstrap in my Angular 5 project by providing the path as follows,

```
"styles": [
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

Shouldn't it be (Note the number of dots in front of node_modules),

```
"styles": [
"styles.css",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

provided node_modules and .angular-cli.json are in the same folder? (Root folder)

Comment: No, `.angular-cli.json` is just a config file. The "virtual path" (probably not the right term) is under `src` so you need that `../`

Comment: Then why this?  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json", instead of "../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json" ? I got your point @12seconds. But I am just wondering why is $schema so

Comment: `.angular-cli.json` doesn't just contains config for stuff under `src`. For stuff like `styles` and `scripts`, they belong in `src`. Basically it's a `config` for `angular-cli` webpack. So if you look at the `src code` for angular-cli webpack you will understand it more.

Comment: I'd say that the path defined in `styles` and `scripts` for each app is relative to the `root` setting defined for the app (which is `src` by default). For the `$schema"` example, it's defined outside of the `apps` scope, so it's really at the root project level

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanations